# Installation & Configuration of Gremlin-neo4j in windows

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

Hi i am new to gremlin and neo4j anyone please tell me how to install and configure this database.
I use this http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/ link for reference but i con't configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really old version of TinkerPop you are referencing in that link. The latest version is 3.3.3, please considering using that.

The most simple way to get started is to just create a `Graph` instance which will start Neo4j in an embedded mode:

```
Graph graph = Neo4j.open('data/neo4j');
GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();
List<Vertex> vertices = g.V().toList()
```

To have greater control over the Neo4j specific configuration rather than all the defaults then you will want to create a properties file or `Configuration` object and pass that to `open()` rather than a directory where your data is:

```
Configuration conf = new BaseConfiguration();
conf.setProperty("gremlin.neo4j.directory","/tmp/neo4j");
conf.setProperty("gremlin.neo4j.multiProperties",false);
conf.setProperty("gremlin.neo4j.conf.dbms.transaction.timeout","60000s");
Graph graph = Neo4jGraph.open(configuration);
GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();
List<Vertex> vertices = g.V().toList()
```

I'd suggest sticking to embedded mode initially, but connecting in high availability mode is also possible using the "configuration" approach above with specifics defined [here in the documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_high_availability_configuration).